# Flash AS3 Full Screen not working on a tablet PC

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, tablet

I have a Flash (AS3, CS3) piece that has a button that will make the piece go full screen.

```
stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

This works great in all of the computers that I have tested it in except a tablet PC (HP 2710p is the only tablet I have to test on, but I hear the same behavior happens on all tablets).

Does anyone know the reason for this issue or a work around?

Thanks

---

Additional:

The scale mode is set to exact fit, but I have tried the other options as well:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the issue on a forum.  It turns out that on tablet PCs, you have to turn off hardware acceleration for Flash to go full screen.

You can turn off hardware acceleration by right clicking on the Flash piece, selecting settings, then in the first tab, uncheck "Enable hardware acceleration".